# Angular6 pipe filter run slow on large array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have this filter that return a subset of items from a big array (around 500 items in this array)

```
    import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
     name: 'searchFilter'
    })

    @Injectable()
    export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: any, ...args): any {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
        console.log(value, args);
       if ( typeof args[0] === 'undefined') {
        return value;
       } else if (value) {
           return value.filter(item => {
               // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
               for (let key in item) {
                   if ((typeof item[key] === 'string' || item[key] instanceof String) &&
                        (item[key].toUpperCase().indexOf(args[0].toUpperCase()) !== -1)) {
                            return true;
                        }
               }
           });
       }
    }

    }
```

Whenever i type in the text box, it takes a few sec for the character actually show up in the box, and another few sec to return update the list to return the search items.

I tried to add in the `slice:0:10` to limit the number of item on screen, but it has the same issue, so i am guessing the slowness is due to the big array and not the screen rendering.

I have talked to the back end developer, and since this array is used by other people, he won't be modifying it. What can i do to improve the performance?

edit: include html code:

```
    <form *ngFor='let subarray of array | searchFilter: filterText | slice:0:20 ; let i = index;' #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Save(form)">
      <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="country" [ngModel]="subarray.country ">
            <input type="number" name="number" [ngModel]="subarray.number ">
            ............about 24 input fileds in total ..............
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant part of your component's HTML template.

Comment: hi first remove the console log, if you have a big print it will slow thing , second value is the 500 size array? if so what is the size of each item

Comment: @cyrix included the html code

Comment: Adding 24 dom elements for 500 entries in an array will be costly, period. The best thing I can think of to improve performance drastically would be to use some sort of virtual scroll, but the thing you have to keep in mind when doing that is that every element must be exactly the same height. If you can't guarantee that, you will run into scrolling issues.

Comment: @AmitWagner um. . .  i removed the console log, it did help a bit. but there are still a small delay on the text box and the result. each item have about 6 attributes and one more array within, but that array has about max of 13 attributes

Comment: Put some `console.log` or `counter++` debugging logic in different places, and make sure the number of times that code is being run is what you're expecting. I suspect it's recreating the whole form many times a second. Possibly could solve this by making `array` into `array$ | async` and make it a behaviorsubject. That may trigger it to only update when the actual array has changed.

Comment: If you're saying it's slow *as you type* that suggests it's doing more updates than it should. Read up on change detection too if you're new to angular

Comment: @DevinFields thanks, let me look into that

Comment: It may not solve all of your issues, as @Simon_Weaver pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some performance improvements you should try:

**Use trackBy-function for ngForOf**

Use provide a `trackBy` function for the `ngForOf` directive, for example track all DOM elements by their index:

```
// template:
<div *ngFor="let subarray of array; trackBy:trackByIndex">
  ...
</div>

// component:

public trackByIndex(index: number, value: any)
{
  return index;
}
```

**Don't use a pipe to filter the data** *(for impure pipes)*

Don't use a pipe to filter your large array, because it'll be invoked everytime the changedetection runs for the component.

You could for example filter the large array if the search input changes:

```
// component:
public originalData: any[] = [...];
public filteredData: any[] = this.originalData;

// ...

public filterData(searchString: string)
{
   this.filteredData = this.originalData.filter(item => {
     // your filter logic
   })
}
```

**Enrich your every item by a searchable string**

Enrich every item inside the array by a searchable string. If you want to search all values of an item just map the array once and append a new key to the item like:

```
this.originalData = this.dataService.getData().map(item => {
   return {
     ...item,
     searchableString: Object.values(item).join(':'),
   }
})
```

This prevents you from running through every item while filtering. You will just search inside that property for the input string.

```
item.searchableString.indexOf(input) > -1
```

**Other techniques**

- Debounce user search inputs
- Filter the data inside a service using a BehaviorSubject together with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and making the data an input of your list component

**Sidenote**

Keep in mind that the performance in development mode of angular is far worse than in production mode. In development mode every changedetection is run twice. Also AOT-mode will bring a lot of performance improvements.

Comment: Debouncing the search term input wouldn't hurt, too.

Comment: Was about to add that ;) There are plenty  more options, like using a service together with a subject and onPush change detection

Comment: `Don't use a pipe to filter your large array, because it'll be invoked everytime the changedetection runs for the component.` I checked again today and it's false, many people tell others to avoid it, while it has no performance impact, as long as the input is the same, the pipe transform method won't be called. What you should avoid at all cost is data bind a function call. Proof: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkyjat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The fact that he is filtering the array needs him to mark the pipe as "impure", therefore it's invoked everytime. It only would be a pure pipe if there's no internal state and you can be 100% sure all the inputs are immutable.

Comment: Either I am missing something or he does not set his pipe to `pure: false`. Anyway, I think it would be great to add a note about it in your answer.

Comment: Yeah he missed it or doesn't know about it, at least by the definition of the angular team it has to be marked as impure. That's why for example the `json`-pipe and the `slice`-pipe are marked as impure. But thanks for your comment, added a note to my answer ;)

Comment: @Ploppy the "many people" that tell others to avoid it is literally the angular team: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe You can avoid a performance hit by enforcing immutability on your array but the maintainability, reusability and ease to understand is far lower than filtering your arrays yourself when you would have had to re reference it.

Comment: Yeah, but this applies only for impure pipes, the problem is that I see people saying to avoid pipes globally because they are called every single digestion cycle which is not true. Anyway, you nailed it, keep going ;)

Comment: @cyrix Thanks, it took me some time, but i was able to improve performance using the searchable string

Answer (score 0):

You need to **remember** the previous state of the filter in order to gain performance.

Let's assume you have a long list of 500 strings that looks something like this.

```
const originalValues = ['a', 'and', 'goo', 'apple', 'antelope', ...];
```

When the user types `a` you filter the above values like this.

```
const newValues = values.filter((value) => value.indexOf(input) !== -1);
console.log(newValues);
```

The above will print something like this.

```
['a', 'and', 'apple', 'antelope']
```

The next letter the user types updates the search `input` and you can filter `newValues` a second time. Each time the user adds a letter to their input term you can filter the *previous* results again. As long as the user is making the input string longer.

This can not be done via a pipe, because pipes don't remember the previous state. You'll have to do something special in the component to handle this.

You also need to **abort** when you hit the result limit. This way you are not iterating the entire collection when you've found a limit of 20.

```
 const newValues = [];
 for(let value of values) {
     if(newValues.length === 20) {
          break;
     }
     if(value.indexOf(input) !== -1) {
        newValues.push(value);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be a memoization pattern.

If, e.g., that is your pipe

```
// excerpt
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
   return this.myOwnTransformingMethod(args, value);
}
```

you can use memo-decorator for this method, like

```
@memo()
private myOwnTransformingMethod(args: any[], value: any) {
// do some filtering or transformations and
return value;
}
```

You don't have to implement the pattern on your own. There is one you can use (MIT license):

```sh
npm i memo-decorator -S
```

and import it in your `whatever.pipe.ts`

```sh
import memo from 'memo-decorator';
```